# $f(n) = \Sigma_{d|n} \mu(n/d)F(d)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mobius-function, multiplicative-function, mobius-inversion

The question says:

> If $F(n) = \Sigma_{d|n} f(d)$ for every positive integer $n$, prove that $f(n) = \Sigma_{d|n} \mu(n/d)F(d)$.

What I know so far is that divisors of $n$ can be paired together. Hence, using ***mobius inversion formula***, the following holds true:

$$f(n) = \Sigma_{d|n}\mu(\frac{n}{d})F(\frac{n}{d})$$

However, it is not exactly the same as in the question.

The question is from **An introduction to The Theory of Numbers** by *Ivan Niven*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in the problem is the Mobius inversion formuala (see the link below with the substitution of $n/d$ into $d$):

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_inversion_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)

You quoted the formula incorrectly.

Comment: "with the substitution of n/d into d"

How to do so??

Comment: Oh thanks, I understood now.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very useful if it was written as a hint:

Use mobius formula with the following substitution:

> $$d = \frac{n}{d}$$